# Wrap every child divisible by 5 and previous 4 in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, parent-child

I've been working on this JSFiddle to practice my understanding of jquery, but now I'm stuck.

How do you wrap a child element in a div to follow this pattern: child elements 1-5, then child elements 6-10, then child elements 11-15, and so on?

I'm working on a tally counter, so I want every 5 tallies to cluster together. That way, I can more easily select the last child and apply a class to make it rotate, in order to "cross out" the previous 4 tallies.

**edit:** (To clarify: I've been looking into selecting by index and by nth-child/nth-of-type, but those methods can only really grab the fifth element, or maybe even multiples of five? It doesn't grab the previous divs, too.)

**edit 2:** (So, you can actually use those selectors! I figured I was getting something wrong. It's always something simple.)

```
$(".button").click(function() {

  var $button = $(this);
  var oldValue = $button.parent().find("input").val();

  if ($button.text() == "+") {
      var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) + 1;
    } else {
   // Don't allow decrementing below zero
    if (oldValue > 0) {
      var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) - 1;
    } else {
      newVal = 0;
    }
  }

  $("#counternumber").val(newVal);

});

$("#plus").click(function() {
    var tally = "<div class='tally'>I</div>";
    $("#dummy").append(tally)
    });
$(function(){
    $('#scratchpad.tally:nth-of-type(5)').wrap('tallyfamily');
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fredlyin/Hfz9L/17/).

Comment: If you're only wrapping them to get the last child it's much easier to just do `#scratchpad.tally:nth-child(5n)` to get every fifth element.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a general solution to wrap elements in groups of 5:

```
$(".holder > div:nth-child(5n-4)")
    .addClass("first-of-group")
    .each(function(){
        $(this).nextUntil(".first-of-group")
               .addBack()
               .wrapAll("<div class='wrapper'>"); 
    })
    .removeClass("first-of-group");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nJJM8/1/

Basically, `:nth-child(5n-4)` gets the first element in each group of 5.  Then a class is temporarily added to keep track of these.  `nextUntil` is used to find all elements up until the next element with that class.  And finally `wrapAll` is used to wrap the matched elements in a div.

**EDIT:**  Even easier:

```
var $divs = $(".holder > div");
for (var i = 0; i < $divs.length; i += 5) {
    $divs.slice(i, i + 5).wrapAll("<div class='wrapper'>");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kMzeN/1/

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there, but a couple of things to note.  You will only call your "wrap" function once, as it's outside of the click event.  If you are dynamically adding, then you'll want to call it each time.

Secondly, with the HTML in your fiddle, you will never get the 5th record because you are appending your selector is looking for the 5th element with ID "scratchpad" with the class of tally.  You'd need to change your selector to something that looks for all tallies, like so:

```
$(".tally:nth-of-type(5)").css('color', 'red');
```

I've updated the fiddle you were working on, and my code highlights each 5th record, so you can see what's going on.  You were close, but you'll also want to add to your "nth-of-type" selector the use of "n", this way it gets every 5th record, not just the 5th one.  So the full function becomes this

```
$("#plus").click(function() {
    var tally = "<div class='tally'>I</div>";
    $("#dummy").append(tally);
    $(".tally:nth-of-type(5n)").css('color', 'red');
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Hfz9L/16/

Answer (score 1):

Check this [**Working Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Hfz9L/25/)

```
$("#plus").click(function() {
    var tally = "<div class='tally'>I</div>";
    $("#dummy").append(tally);
    $('#scratchpad .tally:nth-of-type(5n+1)').prevUntil('span').wrapAll('<span style="margin-right:5px;color:red;text-decoration:line-through;"></span>');
});
```

---

```
$('#scratchpad .tally:nth-of-type(5n+1)').prevUntil('span').wrapAll('<span style="margin-right:5px;color:red;text-decoration:line-through;"></span>');
```

Some changes:

1. `$('#scratchpad .tally:nth-of-type(5n+1)')` and not `$('#scratchpad.tally:nth-of-type(5)')`. - `.tally` is the child of `#scratchpad` ; selector to be used `:nth-of-type(5n+1)`
2. Use **[.wrapAll()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/)** - to wrap the selected elements in a `<span>` or any other element.
3. **[.prevUntil()](http://api.jquery.com/prevuntil/)** - get all the previous elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a `for` loop and do this:

```
for(i=1;i<=noOfChildElements/5;i++)
{
    $('.child:nth-child('+i+'), .child:nth-child('+(i+1)+'), .child:nth-child('+(i+2)+'), .child:nth-child('+(i+3)+'), .child:nth-child('+(i+4)+')').wrapAll("<div />");
}
```

Basically I'm going through the child elements in the for loop and at every turn of the loop I'm selecting the 5 next child elements and wrapping them in a div using the [.wrapAll()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/) function. Hope this helps.

Comment: This isn't going to work correctly because after your first iteration, the first 5 elements will be place in a wrapper.  That wrapper will be the first child and the elements that were previously 6-10 will now be 2-6.  Similar on the next 11-15 will then be 3-7.

Comment: Also your concatenation will happen before addition, so `nth-child('+i+1+')` will become `nth-child(11)` when `i` is 1 instead of `nth-child(2)` as I suspect you intend.  You'll need parentheses:  `nth-child('+(i+1)+')`

Answer (score 1):

To rotate (or apply any other property) to each 5th element, you don't even need to wrap them. Just specify a css class using the `nth-of-type(5n)` and it will affect every 5th element.

```
#scratchpad .tally:nth-of-type(5n) {
    display: inline-block;
    transform:rotate(20deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(20deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform:rotate(20deg); /* Opera, Chrome, and Safari */
}
```

Here is your fiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/Hfz9L/20/